# Silverpop data transfer via curl returns Session expired or invalid

Tags: php, curl

I'm new for the most part to the world of PHP. I'm currently attempting to interface Silverpop's API with forms on our pages. Below is the code I have so far.

The problem is that while authentication works just perfectly, whenever I try to POST the XML the API requires, I'm always returned an error that says: "Session has expired or is invalid."  I'll mark the areas in the code where the error occurs.

I've spent the last half a day researching and I cannot figure out what it is I am doing wrong or what I might be missing.  I was told vaguely it has something to do with output in the browser a before PHP header function like cURL, but that has been little help since I'm testing this in a blank (no html) php file.

```
<?php
// Vars
$firstname = 'a';
$lastname = 'a';
$email = 'a@b.com';

// cURL
function curl($url,$header,$postbody) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postbody);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $ret;
}

///# SILVERPOP API #///

// SILVERPOP API URLs
    // get_token uses oauth to retrieve an access token (works just fine)
$get_token = 'https://api1.silverpop.com/oauth/token?*inforemoved*';
$xmlapi = 'https://api1.silverpop.com/XMLAPI?Authorization=';

// XML STRINGS
$xml_post = '<Envelope><Body><AddRecipient><LIST_ID>database#</LIST_ID><CREATED_FROM>1</CREATED_FROM><SEND_AUTOREPLY>true</SEND_AUTOREPLY><UPDATE_IF_FOUND>true</UPDATE_IF_FOUND><COLUMN><NAME>Name</NAME><VALUE>'.$firstname.'</VALUE></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>LastName</NAME><VALUE>'.$lastname.'</VALUE></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>Email</NAME><VALUE>'.$email.'</VALUE></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>Lead Source</NAME><VALUE>Lead_SqueezePage_5Questions</VALUE></COLUMN></AddRecipient></Body></Envelope>';
$xml_done = '<Envelope><Body><Logout/></Body></Envelope>';

// HEADER VALUES
$h_access = 'Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded';
$h_api = 'Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8';

// Get API Access token
$auth = curl($get_token,$h_access,'');

// Pull access_token from the return string
$auth = explode('"', $auth);

for ($i=0; $i < count($auth); $i++) {
    if ( $auth[$i] == "access_token" ) {
        $access_token = $auth[$i + 2];
        break;
    } 
}

//Append token to URL unless auth failed, then die
if ( $access_token != NULL) {

    $xmlapi .= $access_token;

} else {
    // Logout API session - SESSION ERROR HERE
    $logout = curl($xmlapi,$h_api,$xml_done);
    //echo 'Authentication Failed!';
    die;
}

// Send Customer Data - SESSION ERROR HERE
$inject = curl($xmlapi,$h_api,$xml_post);

// Logout API Session - SESSION ERROR HERE
$logout = curl($xmlapi,$h_api,$xml_done);

///# END SILVERPOP API #///
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get cURL to work properly.  I hope the code below helps someone who's working with the Silverpop API for the first time and is getting stuck.

Retrieve an access key from Silverpop:

```
    // POST Fields
    $fields = array(
        'client_id' => CLIENT_KEY,
        'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
        'refresh_token' => REFRESH_TOKEN,
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    );

    // Init cURL
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set Options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ACCESS_KEY_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

    // Execute cURL
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for HTTP and sever errors here if you wish
    // with curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)

    // Close Connection
    curl_close($ch);

    // Now you can work with the returned $result string
```

Send XML request envelope to Silverpop:

```
// Set POST header
        $header = array(
            'Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8','Authorization: Bearer '.$access_key
        );

        // init cURL
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, REQUEST_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($xml_post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post);
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really useful for a quick, simple contact form implementation where I didn't want to add Composer and a whole new library to a very simple project...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send back the cookies to keep your session alive. try to add this options to your curl request.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`

this species the filename where the cookies should be stored. If the server sets any they will be written to this file, and it will be created if it does not already exist.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

The cookie jar setting is where curl writes cookies to, but a separate setting is required for curl to send cookies back to the server. This is the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE setting. If it is not set then no cookies will be sent to the server. If the file does not exist, then no error is issued.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
```

You will need to replace `/tmp/cookies.txt` with your own path.

Comment: I was a good shot, but it didn't change anything.   I'm wondering if I'm applying the application token correctly.  I now think this is less a session issue on my server and more an issue on their side where they're not able to accept my token for some reason and thus create a "valid" session.   Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can only request a certain number of access tokens in an hour.
In your code, it looks like you're mixing OAuth authorisation and jsession login/logout.

If you have an access token (requested via OAuth), save your access token in e.g. the session as it'll be valid for 4 hours.
The curl headers will need to include the token in the request:

```
$curlHeaders[] = "Authorization: Bearer {$accessToken}";
```

the xml logout command is used when you've authenticated to the api with a username/pass.
the login command will give you a jsessionid that you then use in each request (**instead of** the access token).

the script I'm currently using saves the access token in the session along with the expiry time/date. when the Silverpop Connector fires off an xml command, it checks the access token, which subsequently checks if it's about to expire or already expired and if yes, requests a new one.

```
$getNewToken = true; //assume you need a new access token
//check if the session has an access token
if (!empty($_SESSION['access'])) {

//check access token is present and not expired
if ( ($expiry > (time() + 5)) && (!empty($token)) ) { 

//set current access token in the Connector, no new access token required
SilverpopConnector::getInstance()->setAccessToken($token,$expiry); 
$getNewToken = false;

//if the session wasn't set or token in session invalid/expired:
if ($getNewToken) { 
//get access token & expiry from the Connector (will authenticate if expired/invalid)
$accessToken = SilverpopConnector::getInstance()->getAccessToken();
$tokenExpiry = SilverpopConnector::getInstance()->getAccessTokenExpiry();
//2a. if successful, set in session
//2b. if not successful, check if you're connected/re-connect
```

The Silverpop Connector I mention above is a script created by mrmarkfrench on GitHub.
Please check out https://github.com/mrmarkfrench/silverpop-php-connector

Hope this helps,
Sandra.

Comment: Thanks!   I totally forgot about posting this, but I answered my own question months ago.   I'll edit my post to include my solution.   Thanks for taking the time regardless.   I hope this helps someone new to the Silverpop API themselves.